# onClick() doesn't work and counter stopped at specific number without adding it all up

Tags: javascript, html, css, counter, onload-event

```js
var r, g, b, color1, color2, exclude_box;
var count = 0;

function changeColor() {
  r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  color1 = "rgb(" + r + " , " + g + " , " + b + ")";
  color2 =
    "rgb(" +
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) +
    " , " +
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) +
    " , " +
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) +
    ")";

  exclude_box = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9 + 1);

  for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
    if (i == exclude_box) {
      continue;
    } else {
      var box_id = "box" + i;
      document.getElementById(box_id).style.backgroundColor = color1;
    }

    document.getElementById("box" + exclude_box).style.backgroundColor = color2;
  }
}

function playGame() {
  const onClick = (event) => {
    var clicked = event.srcElement.id;
    if (clicked == "box" + exclude_box) {
      count++;
      document.getElementById("point").textContent = "Points :" + count;
      changeColor();
    } else {
      window.alert("Game Over");
      count = 0;
      document.getElementById("point").textContent = "Points :" + count;
      location.reload();
    }
  };
  var clickMe = document.getElementById("box" + exclude_box)
  clickMe.addEventListener("click", onClick);
}
```

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  gap: 50px;
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-right: 25%;
}

.colorBox {
  width: 150px;
  height: 180px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Color Box</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="homework.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="changeColor()">
        <h1 style="text-align: center;">Color Game</h1>
        <h3 id="point" style="text-align: center;">Points: 0</h3>
        <h2 id="oddbox"></h2>
        <div class="grid-container">
            
            <div class="colorBox" id="box1" onClick="playGame()"> </div>
            <div class="colorBox" id="box2" onClick="playGame()"> </div>
            <div class="colorBox" id="box3" onClick="playGame()"> </div>
            <div class="colorBox" id="box4" onClick="playGame()"> </div>
            <div class="colorBox" id="box5" onClick="playGame()"> </div>
            <div class="colorBox" id="box6" onClick="playGame()"> </div>
            <div class="colorBox" id="box7" onClick="playGame()"> </div>
            <div class="colorBox" id="box8" onClick="playGame()"> </div>
            <div class="colorBox" id="box9" onClick="playGame()"> </div>

        </div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

The idea of this color game is to choose the different color box from out of all 9 boxes, if the user chooses the odd color box, it gains one point, however, if the user fails to choose the odd color box, the program alerts "Game Over". In my program, the code works, however, in order to gain points for choosing odd color block, I happen to do click twice instead of one and after the points reached 7, it no longer adds up points and said it's Game Over even though I choose the odd color block

Comment: You don't add the click listener to the excluded box until you call `playGame()`, and that doesn't happen until you click on another box.

Comment: Why do you need the `if` statement in the click listener? It's only added to the excluded box, so how could the condition be false?

Comment: @Barmar oh right, I was planning to get the Id of whatever the div that is clicked and see if it matches with excluded box id. Am I supposed to add all clickListener to all div elements of the blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add an event listener in the `playGame()` function. That's the function that runs when the user clicks on a box, so you should just put the check for whether it's the odd color box.

Also, `event.srcElement` is obsolete, you should use `event.target`.

```js
var r, g, b, color1, color2, exclude_box;
var count = 0;

function playGame(event) {
  var clicked = event.target.id;
  if (clicked == "box" + exclude_box) {
    count++;
    document.getElementById("point").textContent = "Points :" + count;
    changeColor();
  } else {
    window.alert("Game Over");
    count = 0;
    document.getElementById("point").textContent = "Points :" + count;
    location.reload();
  }
}

function changeColor() {
  r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  color1 = "rgb(" + r + " , " + g + " , " + b + ")";
  color2 =
    "rgb(" +
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) +
    " , " +
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) +
    " , " +
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) +
    ")";

  exclude_box = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9 + 1);

  for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
    if (i == exclude_box) {
      continue;
    } else {
      var box_id = "box" + i;
      document.getElementById(box_id).style.backgroundColor = color1;
    }

    document.getElementById("box" + exclude_box).style.backgroundColor = color2;
  }
}
```

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  gap: 50px;
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-right: 25%;
}

.colorBox {
  width: 150px;
  height: 180px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Color Box</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="homework.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="changeColor()">
  <h1 style="text-align: center;">Color Game</h1>
  <h3 id="point" style="text-align: center;">Points: 0</h3>
  <h2 id="oddbox"></h2>
  <div class="grid-container">

    <div class="colorBox" id="box1" onClick="playGame(event)"> </div>
    <div class="colorBox" id="box2" onClick="playGame(event)"> </div>
    <div class="colorBox" id="box3" onClick="playGame(event)"> </div>
    <div class="colorBox" id="box4" onClick="playGame(event)"> </div>
    <div class="colorBox" id="box5" onClick="playGame(event)"> </div>
    <div class="colorBox" id="box6" onClick="playGame(event)"> </div>
    <div class="colorBox" id="box7" onClick="playGame(event)"> </div>
    <div class="colorBox" id="box8" onClick="playGame(event)"> </div>
    <div class="colorBox" id="box9" onClick="playGame(event)"> </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Bamar Thank you. It works perfectly now. I was quite unfamiliar with eventListeners.